# PHP ternary statement using 'and'

Tags: php

Ok so I just realized some wierd behavior with PHP and would like to know why this happens. So running this code:

```
 var_dump( true and false ? 'one' : 'two' );
```

Outputs

```
boolean true
```

instead of 'two' as you would expect... The problem appears to be using 'and'.

Running:

```
var_dump( true && false ? 'one' : 'two' );
```

outputs

```
string 'two' (length=3)
```

just as expected. Why does using 'and' instead of '&&' cause this weird behavior? Are they not supposed to be the same?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this. My guess is the order.. In the first one, false is used for the ternary operator which comes out to true and 'two', which evaluates to true...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `?:` has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `and`, but lower than `&&`.

Comment: Wow, that's just silly. Is there a logical reason `and` and `&&` don't have equal precendence?

Comment: Now that just makes no sense on why they did that... now I realize that using $one and $two || $three for example is not the same as $one && $two || $three. Thanks for this.

Comment: @dtbarne @Zaptree: There actually is a fairly simple reason for having two distinct boolean and logical operators with different precedences. `||` and `&&` are used to concatenate and alternate boolean expressions, whereas `or` and `and` are used cases like `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` (which is obviously bad code), i.e. they are more alternating or concatenating logic.

Comment: Have to ask, but when I put code $result = mysql_query(..) and echo(mysql_error()). What is exacly happening? I will have to experiment with this operators since I don't use them at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `and` have lower priority than `&&` and `?:`.